# Hibernate deletion referential integrity constraint violation on many to many association

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to use Hibernate to remove an entity however I get an error: `Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`

The setup is that I have an abstract class A and two classes (B and C) which extend A. B contains a list of C's (unidirectional relationship). And there is a function to delete A by its ID.

Note: Stuff has been removed for brevity.

```
@Entity
public class B extends A {
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_A_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "C_A_id"))
  List<C> cList;
}

@Entity
public class C extends A {

  (no reference to B)

}
```

The issue is that when the deleteAByFixedId is called where A is a C, it tries to delete the C before it deletes the B which references it and therefore I get a foreign key constraint failure.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could u please add "A" class...

Comment: Why? It doesn't add anything to the question. My question is about unidirectional vs bidirectional association with many to many relationships, something I don't understand when one subclass reference another.

Comment: Try my answer below. If there would be questions - write to me in the comments)

Comment: Did it worked for u?

Answer (score 1):

*The answer will still be updated.*

Links:

1. [The best way to use the @ManyToMany annotation with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)
2. [Hibernate Inheritance Mapping](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance)

## @ManyToMany

### `Unidirectional` example:

#### User.java

```java
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long id;

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    public void addRoles(Role role) {
        roles.add(role);
    }

    public void removeRoles(Role role) {
        roles.remove(role);
    }
}
```

#### Role.java

```java
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;
}
```

### `Bidirectional` example:

#### Trader.java:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = "stockmarkets")
@Table(name = "trader")
public class Trader {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "trader_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "trader_name")
    private String traderName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "TRADER_STOCKMARKET",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "trader_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "stockmarket_id") })
    private Set<Stockmarket> stockmarkets = new HashSet<>();


    /*
    We need to add methods below to make everything work correctly
     */

    public void addStockmarket(Stockmarket stockmarket) {
        stockmarkets.add(stockmarket);
        stockmarket.getTraders().add(this);
    }

    public void removeStockmarket(Stockmarket stockmarket) {
        stockmarkets.remove(stockmarket);
        stockmarket.getTraders().remove(this);
    }

}
```

#### Stockmarket.java

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = "traders")
@Table(name = "stockmarket")
public class Stockmarket{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "stockmarket_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "stockmarket_name")
    private String stockmarketName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="stockmarkets")
    private Set<Trader> traders = new HashSet<>();

    /*
    We need to add methods below to make everything work correctly
     */

    public void addTrader(Trader trader) {
        traders.add(trader);
        trader.getStockmarkets().add(this);
    }

    public void removeTrader(Trader trader) {
        traders.remove(trader);
        trader.getStockmarkets().remove(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain for my example whether I want a unidirectional or bidirectional

Comment: @ChrisJohnston If you want B to refer to C and C not to B, then you need to use `unidirectional`. If you need B to refer to C and C to B, then you need to use `bidirectional`

Comment: I only want B to refer to C so yes unidirectional but I want it to be bidirectional in the sense that if C is deleted it needs to delete B (which refers to C) first which at the moment it is not doing.

Comment: @ChrisJohnston u can write bidirectional, but use it mostly as unidirectional)